# how to get list of subclass with in super class using java reflection in android project

Tags: java, reflection

When you go through android Hello world app, open the jar file that contains `android.view` package and look at `AbsSavedState.Class` you can see that it is a super class.

How can I display all  its sub classes (inner classes) using java reflection?

Comment: Subclasses and inner classes aren't the same thing - which do you mean? And can you give us more details about why you want to do this?

Comment: hi it is sub-class only.. i mean that bellow all class that are present in android.view package  am doing an android project ...one thing  i observe ..the AbsSavedState class will establish chain link with all  ..if u want to know ..please go through developers.android site ...please ...and tell me  if u find  any way to access

Comment: "class will establish chain link with all" means nothing to me. Please put more effort into expressing yourself clearly. It's still not clear *why* you're trying to do this.

Comment: i mean AbsSavedState is super class using that class i want to access all sub class.

Comment: Right, but for the third time: *why* are you trying to do that?

Comment: i'm going to develop testing tool so the first task i want to access the all class inside.

Comment: What do you mean by "inside"? Again, you seem to be getting confused between *inner* classes and *subclasses*. They're completely different. Why does your testing tool need to know all subclasses of `AbsSavedState`? What are you trying to test, and how does knowing all the subclasses help?

Comment: Classes in the same *package*? That's a whole different request again! You've now listed three different sets of classes you're interested in: 1) Subclasses; 2) Nested classes; 3) Classes in the same package. And you still haven't given any concrete reason why you think you need them.

Comment: reason is  that when we got that classes. using that classes we can get way to access the methods that are in side all classes so using that methods,interfaces ,public fields.we are going to test the each   api ..this is what i am going to do sir  if u know please help me to access the classes

Comment: No, because it's *still* not clear which of those you mean - and surely you only want to test your own code, don't you? I'm afraid I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve by this.

Comment: sir i mean subclass only...

Comment: want access from that AbsSavedState super class

Comment: Sorry, that last comment was particularly unclear. I'm afraid at this point I don't think there's much point me continuing to ask questions - we're not getting anywhere...

Comment: finally i mean to say that i am going to develop a testing app to test an api so for that i want access the  classes from the package android.view sir if u know any code ..please send..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like iterating over all declared classes by `AbsSavedState`, selecting only whose superclass is  `AbsSavedState`.

Here is an example:

```
for(Class innerClass: AbsSavedState.class.getDeclaredClasses())
{
    if(innerClass.getSuperclass().equals(AbsSavedState.class))
        {
            System.out.println("Sub inner class: " + innerClass.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to call getClasses() method of Class.

AbsSavedState.Class.getDeclaredClasses()

Comment: As the OP has now clarified that they're interested in subclasses, not nested classes, this won't help.

Comment: you are  right Jon.But as far as i know super class does not have any knowledge of sub classes or child classes